# Don't know how to call method of a class in main

Tags: c++

so I programmed this, I have a main.cpp where I call a method in a class called getData, basically what Im trying to do is for the user to input a departure and destination, and then output the price and time (all the data is stored in a textfile fly.txt)

It doesnt seem that complicated, yet I keep getting errors. Have I declared everything correctly in the header file, and have I called the methods correctly in the main body?

Thanks in advance!

getData.h

```
#ifndef GETDATA_H
    #define GETDATA_H
    #pragma once

class getData
{
public:
getData(String dep,String des)

    ifstream data("fly.txt");
String departure,destination,time;
int price;
    vector<String> flights;
    vector<String> times;
    vector<int> prices;

void getFlights(String dep, String des);
void getTime(String dep, String des);
void getPrice(String dep, String des);
};

#endif
```

getData.cpp

```
#include "getData.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"


getData::getFlights(string dep, string des){
while(data >> departure >> destination >> time >> price){
    if (dep==departure && des=destination)
flights.push_back(departure);
}
}

getData::getPrice(string dep, string des){
while(data >> departure >> destination >> time >> price){
    if (dep==departure && des=destination)
prices.push_back(price);
}

}

getData::getTime(string dep, string des){
while(data >> departure >> destination >> time >> price){
    if (dep==departure && des=destination)
times.push_back(time);
}

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "getData.h"

int main(){
getData test;

cout<<"Where are you flying from?"<<endl;
string ideparture;
cin>>ideparture;
cout<<"Where are you flying to?"<<endl;
string idestination;
cin>>idestination;

getData.getFlights(ideparture, idestination);


keep_window_open("q");
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to post the errors too.

Comment: I tried to fix the errors one by one, but there are way too many. Some examples: String is not spelled with a capital S. He forgets to put void in the definitions for getPrice. He sometimes uses = instead of ==. And so on.

Comment: You shouldn't write this much code before testing any of it. And you shouldn't post this much code in a question before whittling it down to a minimal complete example.

Answer (score 1):

> In main():

getData constructor needs two parameters: getData test(String dep, String des);

> In getData

- define class variables
- #pragma once same as #ifndef GETDATA_H [...]

getData:

```
class getData {
  private:
    std::ifstream data;
    std::string departure,destination,time;
    int price;
    std::vector<std::string> flights;
    std::vector<std::string> times;
    std::vector<int> prices;
  ...
}
```

...

```
(dep==departure && des==destination)
```

...

```
void getData::fn(...)
```

I don't have the patience to find all bugs...

Answer (score 1):

You should verify your variables carefully. A "String" variable type is different than a "string" (note the capitalization). C/C++ and all their derivates are case-sensitive.

Your code:

```
// Header file definition
void getFlights(String dep, String des);

// Implementation file
getData::getFlights(string dep, string des){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Also, can you include an example of "fly.txt" and the results you are expecting to see? std_lib_facilities.h would be helpful, too.